# Listing files with a certain extension

Tags: linux, shell, ls, wildcards

I'm suppose to write a command that would list all files that end in `.tx` with an optional `t` at the end.

So far all I got is listing the files that end in `.tx` which is:

```
ls *.tx
```

Now my problem is how do I add the optional `t` at the end.

Comment: sorry I meant  ls *.tx that would work

Comment: how would I use it in this case?

Comment: What do you expect in here? To list files ending in `.tx` and `.txt` or really want to know if an "optional" character can be attached?

Comment: @tachomi like I already under how to show files ending in .tx but what command will list files that end in .tx with an optional t at the end

Comment: why not just do `ls *.tx *.txt`?

Answer (score 4):

In `bash` with `shopt -s extglob` you can do this:

```
ls -d *.tx?(t)
```

In `bash` with `shopt -s nullglob` you can do this:

```
ls -d *.txt *.tx
```

But this will show the directory content if no such file exists.

If `ls` is not required:

```
find . -type f '(' -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.tx' ')'
```

This would show files in subdirectories, too. With GNU `find` this can be avoided with `find . -maxdepth 1`.

Comment: is there a way to do it without the shopt -s extglob

Comment: (1) The first two commands can be improved by the addition of the `-d` option.  As written now, if you have a directory called `dir.tx`, then either of those commands will *list **the contents of `dir.tx`*** in addition to listing the text files.  `-d` will prevent that.  (2) `-d` will help the second command in another way.  Currently, if it is executed in a directory where there are no text (`.txt` or `.tx`) files, it will list all the files in the current directory.  With `-d`, it will just say **`.`**. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) In the spirit of the first command, the `find` command can be shortened to ```find . -type f -regex '.*\.txt?'``` (assuming GNU find).